How to get user lookup information using Twitter(X) free endpoint "GET /2/users/me" in Postman?
I have created Twitter developer account (Free version) for followers analysis purposes. I got all my credentials. In Free version, it is mentioned that "GET /2/users/me" Endpoint is free to use. I downloaded postman and imported Twitter API v2 collection and tried to use this endpoint by giving all my credentials in the environment.
I tried giving GET "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id" in the URL and in id values column my followers twitter id. But i am getting,
{ "title": "Unauthorized", "type": "about:blank", "status": 401, "detail": "Unauthorized" }
I am not getting because of my version or some other reasons?
Highly appreciated if someone help me in this! Thank you

"it is mentioned that "GET /2/users/me" Endpoint is free to use." And that's different from /2/users/:id which isn't available with the Free access tier.
